# xdg-open backend

Tags: desktop-environment, xdg-open

I'm creating a desktop for Linux. As a result, I'm creating a utility called `ts-open`. However, when `xdg-open` is run, I want it to open `ts-open` when it detects that my desktop is running (just like it opens `kde-open` in KDE.) Is there a way to do this? If it has to be coded into `xdg-open` is there someone that I can speak to?

Comment: Why don't you create a wrapper script called `xdg-open` that calls `ts-open` if your desktop is running and the regular `xdg-open` if it isn't? Is this something that has to ship with your software? Only for you?

Comment: @terdon ```ts-open``` will ship with my software, and ```xdg-open``` will already be present on the system (probably in /usr/bin.) I'd like applications (like Chrome) that are already using ```xdg-open``` to open ```ts-open``` like in any other desktop environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to patch `xdg-open` to detect your desktop environment in `detectDE()`, and add an `open_...()` function that delegates to `ts-open`.

Once your DE is ready, you should contact [the `xdg-utils` maintainers](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/) with a patch, either *via* a [bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Portland&component=xdg-utils), or the [mailing list](https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/portland).

Comment: So just to make sure that I'm getting this right, I need to modify ```xdg-open``` myself, and then once it works, send the ```xdg-utils``` maintainers the modified version?

Comment: Pretty much. "Once it works", and once your DE is released (and perhaps has traction...). You need to modify `xdg-open` yourself to test things while you're developing your DE anyway, but there's no point in submitting a patch until your DE is available to others.

Answer (score 0):

With all the respect to OP and to accepted answer, since `xdg-open` actually opens  anything with the x default application, could an alias possibly do the job?

The following test in my machine brings the taskmanager without a single warning....

```
$ alias xdg-open='xfce4-taskmanager'
```

So setting this alias  `xdg-open=ts-open` when your DE is loaded and unalias xdg-open when your DE is exited, is not enough or i'm missing something ....?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have control over that. For example, when I open Chrome, it internally uses ```xdg-open``` to open downloads. Unfortunately, I don't think I'll be able to set an alias in every application that the user opens. :)

Comment: @VictorTran I have the feeling that once such an alias is set, even if `xdg-open` is  called internally by Chrome should be redirected to the alias of xdg-open (ts-open). But i'm not sure if it works like this. If you want you can give it a try in the meantime :-) . I am not sure how fast xdg devs will implement your request, this is why i'm thinking "workarounds".

Comment: I suppose it can't hurt to give it a try... :)

Comment: @VictorTran Another workaround would be to implement the wrapper comment of terdon. You could build a script with name xdg-open that will point to ts-open, rename old xdg-open to i.e xdg-openn and as soon as users log-out from your DE revert everything back to previous state (remove your script from /usr/bin and rename again the xdg-openn to xdg-open)

Comment: Unfortunately my app doesn't have root access (and that's a good thing, isn't it?) so I won't be able to do that.